# Should Red Hat images destined for Hyper-V servers include a swap partition?

Tags: redhat, hyper-v

Working on producing a Red Hat image for hosting on our internal Windows Server instances running Hyper-V.

Microsoft [recommends](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/redhat-create-upload-vhd) letting WALinuxAgent manage swap for *Azure* deployments - does the same go for "vanilla" Hyper-V deployments on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

That recommendation is specific to Azure, in which the Azure Linux Agent creates swap elsewhere as described in the document you linked to.

In your own Hyper-V images, which are being run on-premise, you should have an appropriate amount of swap.

If you might migrate such virtual machines to Azure in the future, you can create a swap *file* instead of a swap partition. This will allow you to have swap without using a swap partition which would be a potential problem if you moved the VM to Azure.